# mail() отправляет письма только на gmail

Tags: php, sendmail

Есть код:

```
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
        $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
        $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);
    } else if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
        $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
        $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);
    }

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
        'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
        'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

    mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), generateMessage(), $headers );
```

Письма приходят только на `gmail` почту. на все остальные нет.

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` замените на `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @Visman после изменений вообще перестало работать

Comment: Чтобы без проблем отправлять почту средствами php - используйте smtp сервер мейл.ру, яндекс или гугл, т.к. просто с хостинга отправлять почту совсем ненадежно. Посмотрите библиотеку phpmailer на гитхабе. Библиотека проста в использовании, хоть и выглядит на первый взгляд монструозно (мое личное мнение).

Comment: Причем без проблем работает, если (к примеру на яндекс) привязать домен.

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что товарища просто забанили за спам. В любом случае, прежде чем перебирать возможные варианты использования космических кораблей пришельцев - посмотрите что за ошибку-то даёт вам сервер получателя. [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function)